# Why SaveSiteAsTemplate is hidden

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, web-template

In sharepoint 2010 it was able to Save site as template. But in sharepoint 2013 we should Inaktivate Publishing feature to be able to show this link.

I know that there is some workarounds But my quastion is WHY is it hiddin by microsoft ?
Is it for security reason ? 
im working on an organisation there they would like to have a template of a sitecollection, 
but im a little bit worry about creating the template in the workaround way.

would like to know the reason why is it hidden in 2013 ?

Comment: Even in 2010 if you used Publishing site template, Save site as template was not available.

Comment: what is the the connection between this link and publishing feature ? Why should i disable publishin feature ?

Answer (score 0):

If you had *ever* turned had publishing feature turned on, the save as site template link will not come back. You can try to use import/export to export the site, and import into a site that has never had publishing turned on, and then use save as site template from that.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356